# How to deny page access for particular role using cakephp 3?

Tags: cakephp-3.0

It is not working. I want to index method deny for particular role and redirect on other page.

```
 public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
{
    parent::beforeFilter($event);
   $this->Auth->deny(['index']); // it's not working
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you should do the tutorial:

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html

and then you will stumble on something like this in your controller:

```
public function isAuthorized($user)
{
    // deny index action for certain role
    if ($this->request->action === 'index' && $user['role'] === 'particular_role') {
        return false;
    }

    return parent::isAuthorized($user);
}
```

and this in your appController:

```
public function isAuthorized($user)
{
    // Everyone can access everything
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I got error . Strict (2048): Declaration of App\Controller\Admin\UsersController::isAuthorized() should be compatible with App\Controller\AppController::isAuthorized($user = NULL) [APP/Controller\Admin\UsersController.php, line 12]

Comment: you should pass the $user to the isAuthorized method. like the error says. Dit you do the tutorial yet? it is al explained in there